# Is "May our lives be sacrificed" a set Muslim phrase?

Tags: islamic-basis, violence, phrase

I came across a poster [saying](https://www.facebook.com/events/1403508729944936/permalink/1404370123192130/)

> May our lives be sacrificed for prophet Muhammad ﷺ

Is "May our lives be sacrificed" a phrase that occurred around the time of Muhammad, or is it a modern phrase?

Comment: I think its an arab ways of showing affection

Comment: We have that in Farsi as well used to show affection to any sacred or dear individual. Mothers tell that to their children and visa versa for example!

Comment: @infatuated you must consider this similar question and try to provide supporting explanations. 
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/let-my-parents-be-sacrificed-for-you-in-hadith-meaning

Answer (score 3):

```
                                    بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

As much as I made research, I couldn’t find the precise phrase as you mentioned that you said:

> May our lives be sacrificed for Prophet Muhammad ﷺ

And apparently, this phrase “May our lives be sacrificed" can be used as a modern phrase. Although it could be feasible to be used at that time as well. On the whole, it is solely demonstrates the interest and attachment for the Prophet (SAWW).

Of course @Servant-of-Wiser cited a link which could be related to your inquiry (as in has shown in below).

[What is the meaning of "Let my parents be sacrificed for you" in Hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/let-my-parents-be-sacrificed-for-you-in-hadith-meaning)

On the whole, it could be considered as a sincerity phrase which can be used in both period of time (at the time of Prophet Muhammad (S) and at the moment to demonstrate the sincerity of Muslim about their Prophet (Peace be upon him and his family)).

May Allah guide us.