# What is the meaning of "Let my parents be sacrificed for you" in Hadith?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, hadith-interpretation, sahaba

What exactly is the meaning of the Phrase "Let (or Shall) my parents be sacrificed for you" while talking to Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) the companions mostly used for showing respect. What is the meaning behind that?

Comment: A similar phrase is "Our lives be sacrificed for you"...

Comment: https://islamqa.info/ar/176957 has very good explanation fo this term, its in arabic. I hope you can understand this is arabic idiom.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the most significant reason of this issue could be related to this matter that as an unwritten general rule, parents (both of father and mother) are considered as the most dear persons from the viewpoint of everybody. Hence in the mentioned issue as you said:

> Let(or Shall) my parents be sacrificed for you" while talking to
>   Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) the companions mostly used for
>   showing respect

It would indicate that although my parents are counted as my dearest, but I absolutely believe that you are the apostle of Allah and I'm completely at your service (to help you), even I will be satisfied if my parents as my best persons be sacrificed for you.

**Consequently it indicates that how much they are submitting against Allah and his apostle (pbuh).**

Comment: I think it can also be some arabic idiom?

Comment: Perhaps you are right. yes.

Answer (score -4):

People were being sacrifised to allah and hubal at the kaaba long beofre islam. Muhhamads father was supposed to be sacrificed to allah because he was chosen by hubal. They are both pagan Gods of ancient mecca. Get out of that false religion.

https://questionsonislam.com/question/how-did-incident-prophets-father-abdullah-being-vowed-be-sacrificed-take-place

Comment: Your link is about a preislamic custom so your whole answer is based on a falsehood. And the report is about something that happened at least 70 years before Muhammad had his first revelation so the religion now commonly known as Islam didn't exist!